# Navbar Brand Logo Padding On Various Screen Sizes

Tags: html, css

Padding-top: 18px; is the only way that I'm able to get the navbar brand logo to be vertical canter on my computer, and tablet on a site that I'm editing.  However, that messes up the navbar brand logo alignment on my phone.  So, I'm wanting to add @media only screen coding.  However, the site Doesn't appear to respond to that.  Do I currently have any mistakes in the CSS for the @media only screen coding?  Thanks!  :--)

The -40px, and 60px font is Only for testing purposes.

```css
.navbar-brand {
      color: #C0C0C0;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 18px;
    }
/* For Small Phone Layouts */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .nav-item {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .navbar-brand {
        padding-top: -40px;
      }
    }

    /* For Large Phone Layouts */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .nav-item {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .navbar-brand {
        padding-top: -40px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand wow headShake scroll-smoothly" href="#ssb-header">
<img class="SSB-Logo-Animation" src="ssb-img/SSB-Shield-Logo.svg" height="65" alt="logo"></a>
```

Comment: Why did you repeat the same code two times?

Comment: Read it now Shahriar.  :--)

Comment: Yeah I see it now :-) But you are writing the same code for both media queries... If they should be the same, why use a media query then?

Comment: I'm Only at the Testing stage for media only screen coding.  My current phone is somewhat large.   So, is media only screen and (min-width: 600px) what I need for Large phones?  If so, why Isn't my phone responding to my @media only screen coding?  :--)

Comment: I guess you didn't get what I say. The media queries you used here do nothing at all! for both `< 600px` and `> 600px`, you're applying the same styles.

Comment: `if (a >= 600 & a <= 600)` equals to `if (a == any number)`

Comment: A HOW To site that I recently visited said max-width 600px for small phones, and min-width 600px for large phones.  Since you know that the site that had that info was wrong.  what is the Proper for media only screen coding for both small and large phones?  :--)

Comment: I turned Off one of them, and now I have media only screen and (min-width: 480px).  However No changes on my phone.  I need to sleep.  :--)

Comment: Agree with Shahriar that having 2 media queries that do the same thing, doesn't make sense. You're basically saying: Small screens: negative padding. Large screens: also negative padding. Other than that, even when removing one, it doesn't do anything because there is no such thing as negative padding.

Comment: I've Used - Padding before in areas where it helped a Lot!  The Navbar Brand Logo is Way Too Low on Phones!  And so - Padding would Help a Lot.  Even when I have Non - Padding for phones, Nothing is happening.  Also, I  just Changed (.nav-item) to (.nav-item a), and that is a Success.  So, (.navbar-brand) appears to Not be correct for Phones Top Logo Padding.  :--)

Comment: I Added <div class="Top-Logo-Phones-Margin"> with -13 Margin, and that Fixed the Top Logo on Phones Issue.  :--)